# Androdi Studio setDownloadListener não funciona no Android 6.0

Tags: android, webview

Até antes da versão 6.0 o seguinte método abaixo funciona perfeitamente fazendo download de qualquer documento solicitado na WebView..

Porem agora com android 6.0 na tentativa de qualquer download dentro da webview o app trava e diz "A aplicação parou de funcionar.".

O método abaixo fica na mesma classe da webview..
Alguem sabe como pode ser feito o download na versão 6 do android?

```
//Método para download PDF
wv.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {

    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                long contentLength) {
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                Uri.parse(url));

        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED); //Notify client once download is completed!
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "boleto.pdf");
        DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        dm.enqueue(request);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT); //This is important!
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE); //CATEGORY.OPENABLE
        intent.setType("*/*");//any application,any extension
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Baixando Arquivo", //To notify the Client that the file is being downloaded
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
});
```

Comment: Edite a pergunta e coloque o *log* de erro, tenho quase a certeza que é falta de permissões.

Comment: Pesquisei melhor de noite e realmente era isso. O novo sistema de permissões no Android 6 estava bloqueando.. adicionei a solicitação de permissoes para gravar na memoria na classe MAIN e agora a webview baixa arquivos como nas versoes anteriores.